# how to retrive data for individual elements from database and store it into automated divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

what I'm trying to do is, i have a table named hotels and i have a page where peoples can book the hotel based on the room category. now for displaying the hotels I am using a while loop in which datas are fetch and hotels are displayed in automated divs which id same for all. so i added a `$i=1` and added to the id fields and `$i` is incremented at the end of the while loop.
so what error I am getting is I am not able to retrieve the cost of the room category.

here is my code:

php code for getting individual hotels and show it in a div.

```
<?php
include 'mysql.php';
$i = 1;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE location = 'portblair' ") or die("the query cannot be completed at this moment");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) <1) {
    die("no hotels found");
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $hotel_name = $row['name'];
    $hotel_type = $row['type'];
    $hotel_location = $row['location'];
    $hotel_cat1 = $row['cat1'];
    $hotel_cat2 = $row['cat2'];
    $hotel_cat3 = $row['cat3'];
    $hotel_cat4 = $row['cat4'];
    $hotel_cp = $row['cp'];
    $hotel_map = $row['map'];
    $hotel_ap = $row['ap'];
    $hotel_em = $row['em'];
    if($hotel_type == "0"){
        $hotel_star ='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>';
    }
    if($hotel_type == "1"){
        $hotel_star ='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>';
    }
    if($hotel_type == "2"){
        $hotel_star ='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>';
    }
    if($hotel_type == "3"){
        $hotel_star ='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>';
    }
    if($hotel_type == "4"){
        $hotel_star ='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="panel panel-red">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <?php echo $hotel_name; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="images/hotels/<?php echo $hotel_name ?>.png" class="img-responsive"/>
                <div class="my-caption">
                    <?php echo  $hotel_star;  ?>
                </div>
                <select name="hotel_cat" id="hotel_cat[<?php echo $i; ?>]" class="form-control" onchange="hotel_rate()">
                    <option value="">Category</option>
                    <?php if($hotel_cat1 != ""){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $hotel_cat1; ?>"><?php echo $hotel_cat1; ?></option>
                        <?php
                    } ?>
                    <?php if($hotel_cat2 != ""){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $hotel_cat2; ?>"><?php echo $hotel_cat2; ?></option>
                        <?php
                    } ?>
                    <?php if($hotel_cat3 != ""){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $hotel_cat3; ?>"><?php echo $hotel_cat3; ?></option>
                        <?php
                    } ?>
                    <?php if($hotel_cat4 != ""){
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $hotel_cat4; ?>"><?php echo $hotel_cat4; ?></option>
                        <?php
                    } ?>

                </select>
                <span id="add[<?php echo $i; ?>]" >Add</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    $i++;

}
?>
<input  type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"/>
```

so i want a js script that shows the cost of the category of room selected for individual hotels.

here is my js code:

```js
function hotel_rate(){
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var i=1;
  var cnt = $("#count").val();
  for(i=1;i<cnt;i++){
   var cat = $("#hotel_cat["+i+"]").val();
   var test = cat.split(:);
   var cat_cost = parseInt(test[1]);
   $("#add["+i+"]").html("Rs: "+cat_cost+" Add");
  }
  
  
 });
 }
```

and the error iam getting from console is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: hotel_rate is not defined" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined".

any type of help would be appriciated.
thanx in advance.

Comment: Do not use the deprecated `mysql`. Use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: 1st you declare functios. `function hote_rate() { ...without document ready in side of it... }`, then you fire it on document ready. `$(document).ready( { hotel_rate() })`

Comment: i dnt know mysqli yet. :'(

Comment: i didn't got you. plz can u elaborate.

Comment: Also You missed quotes in  `var test = cat.split(:);` it should be `var test = cat.split(':');`

Comment: @SaikatBepari, its almost the same, for the most part only the name is changed.

Comment: even after adding the quotes iam getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: hotel_rate is not defined" when iam selecting the hotel category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery file must be something like this

```
function hotel_rate(){ // just define the function.
    var i=1;
    var cnt = $("#count").val();
    for(i=1;i<cnt;i++){
        var cat = $("#hotel_cat["+i+"]").val();
        var test = cat.split(':'); 
        var cat_cost = parseInt(test[1]);
        $("#add[1]").html("Rs: "+cat+" Add");
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   hotel_rate(); // fire it on document ready
});
```

Also you missed quotes in `var test = cat.split(:);` it should be `var test = cat.split(':');`

Comment: now the console says this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: console.log `$("#hotel_cat["+i+"]").val();` and see what it will show you, and show it here

Comment: it shows that "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: create jsfiddle example with exact that html elements and exact selectors, the problem is not the `hotel_rate()` not firing up, as was before. There is syntax error in the function

Comment: ok gimme some time ill update a jsfiddle and let u know. thanx for the help

Comment: or MB you can try like this, remove the square brackets from the `select` id and make it looks like so `#hotel_cat_1`, so in the `hotel_rate()` function you can access it like so `$("#hotel_cat_"+i)`

Comment: also if it gives an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" it must show the number of the line where was the error

Comment: thanx @manchary-manchaary. your $("#hotel_cat_"+i) idea worked for me... thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: but the only problem now iam getting is. without changing the select value, by defaults hotel_rate() is firing and its showing Rs: NaN Add by default in every hotel before selecting any options.

Comment: oh, right! you have got your `onchange="hotel_rate()"` at the select box, so no need to fire up the `hotel_rate()` function when `$(document).ready()`. it will work on change without problems

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `hotel_rate()`should be inside ready function, also replace `cat.split(:);` by `cat.split(':');` :

```
$(function(){
    function hotel_rate(){
        var i=1;
        var cnt = $("#count").val();
        for(i=1;i<cnt;i++){
            var cat = $("#hotel_cat["+i+"]").val();
            var test = cat.split(':');
            var cat_cost = parseInt(test[1]);
            $("#add[1]").html("Rs: "+cat+" Add");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: still getting two errors.   Uncaught ReferenceError: hotel_rate is not defined and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: hotel_rate is not defined and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: replace `cat.split(:);` by `cat.split(':');`

Comment: yeah i did that. but after adding ':' iam getting this error when iam selecting the category. Uncaught ReferenceError: hotel_rate is not defined

Comment: after adding ur sample code also iam getting same error. Uncaught ReferenceError: hotel_rate is not defined

Comment: Okay try to put an alert before your function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Above two answers is also right.you have to declare function outside document.ready section and split function argument must have string inside it.

here is i put working code example as per your concept.you can also check paste in this fiddle [php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/).

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-red">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Hotel name            </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <img src="images/hotels/Hotel name.png" class="img-responsive"/>
            <div class="my-caption">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>                </div>
            <select name="hotel_cat" id="hotel_cat_1" class="form-control" onchange="hotel_rate()">
                <option value="">Category</option>
                                        <option value="1:50">1</option>

            </select>
            <span id="add[1]" >Add</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input  type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="1"/>
```

```js
<script>
    function hotel_rate(){
  
   var cat = document.getElementById("hotel_cat_1").value;
        alert(cat);
   var test = cat.split(':');
   var cat_cost = parseInt(test[1]);
   document.getElementById("add[1]").innerHTML="Rs: "+cat_cost+" Add";
  }
 
</script>
```

and you are splitting value of cat by ':' for get cost of hotel so in value you must have value with : separator.